# Nginx, Uwsgi, Python - 502 Bad Gateway - upstream prematurely closed connection

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

I've been trying to figure out what's happening, trying solutions for related questiosn, but I had no success.
I'm trying to export some json to xml, and it goes smooth when using not a great amount of data (with a sample of 2000 lines there is no problem). But when I try to make the same request for a bigger file (let's say over 25000 lines) nginx always gives me a **502 Bad Gateway** exactly after one minute. 
All the timeouts on my nginx config file were set to 60s, and I've raised it all to 120s to see if anything changes, but still got the same 502 after only one minute.
Can anyone help?

**Here is how I'm launching uwsgi:**
command=/usr/sbin/uwsgi --buffer-size=320000 --http 0.0.0.0:9090 --wsgi-file /usr/local/cengine/bin/adapter.py --master --processes 50 --max-requests 50 --harakiri 120 --threads 1 --disable-logging --stats 127.0.0.1:9190 --logto /var/log/uwsgi/uwsgi.log

**And here is my nginx config:**

```
#################################################
#                                               #
#   By Puppet                                   #
#                                               #
#################################################
pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;
user              nginx nginx;

daemon  off;

worker_processes  4;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {

#set_real_ip_from xx.xxx.xxx.0/24;
#real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;

## MIME types
include            /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type       application/octet-stream;

## Size Limits
client_body_buffer_size     256K;
client_header_buffer_size   256K;
client_max_body_size         20M;
large_client_header_buffers 8 24k;

## Timeouts
client_body_timeout   120;
client_header_timeout 120;
send_timeout          120;

## General Options
ignore_invalid_headers   on;
keepalive_requests      100;
keepalive_timeout        60;
recursive_error_pages    on;
sendfile                 on;
server_name_in_redirect off;
server_tokens           off;

## TCP options
tcp_nodelay on;
tcp_nopush  on;

## Compression
gzip              on;
gzip_buffers      24 16k;
gzip_comp_level   8;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_min_length   0;
gzip_types        application/x-javascript application/json text/xml text/plain text/css image/x-icon application/x-perl application/x-httpd-cgi application/xml;
gzip_vary         on;
gzip_proxied      any;

## Cache setings
proxy_max_temp_file_size    0;
proxy_connect_timeout      120s;
proxy_send_timeout         120s;
proxy_read_timeout         120s;
proxy_buffer_size          8k;
proxy_buffers              8 64k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size    128k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 128k;
proxy_intercept_errors     on;

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=webcache:1000m inactive=1y max_size=10000m;
proxy_temp_path /var/cache/nginx/tmp;
proxy_cache_min_uses 1;

log_format main  '$remote_addr $host [$time_local] Upstream-cache-status: $upstream_cache_status Cengine-UUID: $upstream_http_x_ceng_uuid "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for" time=$request_time';

log_format cache '$time_local $upstream_cache_status Cache-Control: $upstream_http_cache_control Expires: $upstream_http_expires "$request" ($status) "$http_user_agent"';

upstream uwsgi {
    server 127.0.0.1:9090 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=120s;
    keepalive 20;
}

server {
     server_name xxxxx.tpn.xxxxx.com;
     access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
     access_log  /var/log/nginx/cache.log cache;
     error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
     listen      0.0.0.0:80;
     expires off;

     location / {
         alias /usr/local/getec-fe/;
         index index.html;
     }

    location /files {
        internal;
        alias /anexos;
    }

     location /cengine {
         # regras rewrite
         rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1;
         rewrite ^/cengine/(.*) /$1 break;

         proxy_redirect     off;
         proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
         proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
         #proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
         #proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control Set-Cookie;
         proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
         add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
     #proxy_cookie_path /;
         proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;

     add_header "Cache-Control" "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";

         proxy_pass http://uwsgi;
         #proxy_cache webcache;
         proxy_cache off;
         proxy_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri;
         proxy_cache_valid  any 15s;
         proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     }


    location ~ ^/upload(?<username>/.+)?$ {

          if ( $username = '' )  {
             set $username /api;
          }

          client_body_temp_path      /tmp;
          client_body_in_file_only   clean;
          client_body_buffer_size    128K;
          client_max_body_size       20M;

          proxy_pass_request_headers on;
          proxy_set_header           X-FILE $request_body_file;

          proxy_set_body             off;
          proxy_redirect             off;

          proxy_pass                 http://uwsgi/getec$username/file;

          proxy_set_header Connection "";
          default_type mime-type;

    }


     location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {

         alias /home/$1/public_html/projetos$2;
         index  index.html;
         autoindex on;
     #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
     }

    location /csv {
        alias /tmp/csv;
        add_header Content-Type application/octet-stream;
        add_header Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=\"$arg_filename\"";
    }

     location /status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            allow xxx.xx.xxx.0/24;
            allow xxx.xxx.xx.0/24;
            allow xxx.xxx.xx.0/24;
        allow 98.142.228.0/24;
            deny all;
       }

    location /health_check {
          return 200;
          access_log   off;
     }

    }
}
```

Here is my log for ngnix:

```
2015/04/23 13:21:04 [error] 12335#0: *188 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xx.xxx.x.xx, server: xxx.tpn.xxxx.com, request: "GET /cengine/getec/lucian.thomaz/exporta_csv?tabela=arquivamento&sEcho=1&iColumns=6&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=25&mDataProp_0=ID_ARQUIVAMENTO&mDataProp_1=ID_CONTRATO&mDataProp_2=TP_DOCUMENTO&mDataProp_3=NM_CLIENTE_FORNECEDOR&mDataProp_4=DT_ASSINATURA&mDataProp_5=DS_AREA_RESPONSAVEL&sFilters={%22F_ID_ARQUIVAMENTO%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22ID_ARQUIVAMENTO%22,%22Operador%22:%22eq%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_ID_CONTRATO%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22ID_CONTRATO%22,%22Operador%22:%22eq%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_TP_DOCUMENTO%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22TP_DOCUMENTO%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_NM_CLIENTE_FORNECEDOR%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22NM_CLIENTE_FORNECEDOR%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_NR_CNPJ%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22NR_CNPJ%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_NR_CPF%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22NR_CPF%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_DT_ASSINATURA%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22DT_ASSINATURA%22,%22Operador%22:%22having%22,%22Valor_ini%22:null,%22Valor_fin%22:null},%22F_DS_VALOR%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22DS_VALOR%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_DS_AREA_RESPONSAVEL%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22DS_AREA_RESPONSAVEL%22,%22Operador%22:%22eq%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_BL_ATIVO%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22BL_ATIVO%22,%22Operador%22:%22eq%22,%22Valor%22:%221%22}} HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9090/getec/lucian.thomaz/exporta_csv?tabela=arquivamento&sEcho=1&iColumns=6&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=25&mDataProp_0=ID_ARQUIVAMENTO&mDataProp_1=
```

Here is the log for uwsgi:

```
HARAKIRI: --- uWSGI worker 50 (pid: 12758) WAS managing request /getec/lucian.thomaz/exporta_csv?tabela=arquivamento&sEcho=1&iColumns=6&sColumns=%2C%2C%2C%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=25&mDataProp_0=ID_ARQUIVAMENTO&mDataProp_1=ID_CONTRATO&mDataProp_2=TP_DOCUMENTO&mDataProp_3=NM_CLIENTE_FORNECEDOR&mDataProp_4=DT_ASSINATURA&mDataProp_5=DS_AREA_RESPONSAVEL&sFilters={%22F_ID_ARQUIVAMENTO%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22ID_ARQUIVAMENTO%22,%22Operador%22:%22eq%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_ID_CONTRATO%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22ID_CONTRATO%22,%22Operador%22:%22eq%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_TP_DOCUMENTO%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22TP_DOCUMENTO%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_NM_CLIENTE_FORNECEDOR%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22NM_CLIENTE_FORNECEDOR%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_NR_CNPJ%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22NR_CNPJ%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_NR_CPF%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22NR_CPF%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_DT_ASSINATURA%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22DT_ASSINATURA%22,%22Operador%22:%22having%22,%22Valor_ini%22:null,%22Valor_fin%22:null},%22F_DS_VALOR%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22DS_VALOR%22,%22Operador%22:%22like%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_DS_AREA_RESPONSAVEL%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22DS_AREA_RESPONSAVEL%22,%22Operador%22:%22eq%22,%22Valor%22:null},%22F_BL_ATIVO%22:{%22Model%22:%22Arquivamento%22,%22Coluna%22:%22BL_ATIVO%22,%22Operador%22:%22eq%22,%22Valor%22:%221%22}} since Thu Apr 23 13:20:04 2015 ---
*** HARAKIRI ON WORKER 50 (pid: 12758, try: 2) ***
DAMN ! worker 50 (pid: 12758) died, killed by signal 9 :( trying respawn ...
```

Comment: NGinx was reloaded after changes?

Comment: Yes, @valentin. I've used _sudo nginx -s reload_

Comment: Nginx is logging the fact that the upstream closed the connection. So it'll be an issue behind nginx. Same question of restarting your uwsgi app?

Comment: Yes @dwightgunning, I've restarted the uwsgi app as well. I'm just a bit lost about where to look for, since raising up the timeouts didn't make any difference. May it be comming from the application itself? It's just weird why it's stuck always finishing with 1 minute of execution. I don't know if there is any other place for timeouts that I should look for.

Comment: Perhaps you can set harakiri-verbose and see if you can get some more from the logs. Is it definitely hitting the timeout? I think the workers can hit a memory limit and then harakiri themselves.